# Are there any recommendations for the look of Metro UI table?

Tags: tables, metro, windows-phone-7, windows-8

I can't find any Metro UI example of medium-size table (to give you an idea, min. 5 columns with text and numbers and min. 5 rows).

For instance, when table is wide, it's useful to use alternate row colors (precisely, darker background for even rows). But would it be fine in terms of Metro UI? Or would it be considered as unnecessary 'chrome' and better option would be larger spacing between rows?

And what about thin lines between columns and rows? I see them in calendar app in Windows Phone but calendar is not a table. In other words, I am looking for good examples of Metro (Windows 8) design for regular table of read-only data. Seems basic thing, but I can't find it! Is Metro against table by definition? Sometimes gird / tiles is not the best option and table seems more natural. It's like with  HTML tag - it's still okay to use it when the data you present is a table. I understand the same is correct in Metro world.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, it's very hard to find recommendations on how to implement a useful table in Windows Phone 8, and I think you have to use general conventions on this one, without focusing on Windows 8 style (formerly known as Metro), but keeping the "look and feel" of Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8. That said, this doesn't mean you shouldn't style your app at all. It makes the application unique and (done right) could increase no of downloads and ratings.

On that topic, Jerry Nixon, has made a good and informative guide to start styling your apps called [Windows 8 Beauty Tip: Using a VariableSizedWrapGrid in a GridView makes Grids Prettier](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/windows-8-beauty-tip-using):

> A unique UI is important to make your application stand out. Changing up the grid from the standard, vanilla, boring grid is a great start. Use these techniques to implement the variable grid into your app and start making a splash!

Comment: Thanks. Just a note that this article is about content grid and there are plenty of examples of content grids. I am asking specifically about data grid (table).

Comment: Oh sorry - my bad. I'll see if there is something else out there.